# Opnenms UI error - HTTP ERROR: 503

Tags: opennms

I am facing issue while accessing the opennms UI throwing below error 
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /opennms/alarm/detail.htm. Reason:

```
Service Unavailable
```

OpenNMS Version:    1.10.10

Let me know if you need any trpe of logs detail

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a frustrating answer, but seriously, upgrade. Version 1.10.10 is simply ancient.

The version numbering for OpenNMS has dropped the "1." so you are basically on version "10" while the current version is "22".

If you want to try to fix this on 1.10 the problem is usually caused by an error in a .properties file. What I would do is stop OpenNMS:

`/opt/opennms/bin/opennms stop`

and then remove the log files

`rm -rf /opt/opennms/logs/*`

then restart OpenNMS

`/opt/opennms/bin/opennms start`

While that won't fix the problem, you can then

`cd /opt/opennms/logs`

and then grep for ERROR or FATAL log messages. Those should tell you which file has the problem.